# Getting a partial response from Directory API using fields

Tags: java, partial, google-directory-api

We are trying to retrieve a list of all the domain users. Problem is there are over 13000 users in the domain, so we are timing out. On the developers.google.com, they give tips to improve performance (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/performance). One tip is to retrieve a partial response using the "fields" request parameter. But we cannot figure out what the correct fields are for `fullName` and `primaryEmail`.
We tried using the `setFields("fullName")` method in Java - didn't work. We also tried `name(fullName)`, `names(fullNames)` and they didn't work either.
Same problem for `primaryEmail`. Keep getting the error message: `Invalid field selection -fullName`

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like: setFields("nextPageToken,users(primaryEmail,name(fullName))")